# Test if a property in objectContaining is an Array or undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am using Jest (TypeScript on Node.js) for unit testing and would like to check if a specific property is either an `Array` or `undefined` using `expect.objectContaining()`. This property may or may not exist in the object, hence why I want my test to include both cases.

My initial idea was to use

```
propertyInQuestion: expect.any(Array || undefined)
```

inside `objectContaining()`, but it fails because an `Array` is expected. When I checked the documentation, it stated that an expected object must be a subset of the received object, so it contains properties that are present in the expected object. So what happens when a property is either present and must be of an `Array` type or is undefined and therefore not present in the object?

At the moment, test looks something like this

```
expect(someObject).toEqual(
    expect.objectContaining({
        propertyInQuestion: expect.any(Array),
        something: expect.any(Array),
    })
);
```

and the property I'd like to check is `propertyInQuestion`, which can either be an `Array` or `undefined`.

Any sort of help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: That's weird, you are in unit test env trying to test specific case and you don't know if you get an array or not. :) How random is the function behavior?

Comment: I'm working on a scraper. Property in question is linked to the existence of a specific tag.

Comment: Yeah, but you are unit testing. So I imagine you have 2 cases: it should return an array of something if there (in input data you have crafted) is a specific tag, it should return undefined if there (in another crafted input data) no specific tag. How could it be possible for a unit test to return either/or for a single input?

Comment: I was thinking in the wrong direction then. This comment was insightful, and I thank you for your time and effort.